# How to load the xml data into Hive Table directly without converting it into flat file using java

Tags: xml, import, hadoop, hive

I have some problem with "load XML into Hive table" without converting it into flat file.please help me by providing the necessary things with examples and provide the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely unclear what problem you are having or what you are trying to achieve. You might start with the [xpath UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF) which allows you to query an xml document.